# Chartjs columns does not appear by value

Tags: chart.js

I am using the following dataset,

```
  this.chart = new Chart(
    this.canvasContext,
    {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Population (millions)",
            backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
            data: [2478,5267,734,784,433]
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        showScale: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        utoutPercentage: 50,
        animation: {
          animateRotate: true,
          duration: 2000,
          animateScale: true
        }
      }
    }
  )
```

All columns are appearing.

But If I use the `data: [600,400,400,900,1100]`, 400 values does not appear on chart. They are appearing as zero.

[image]

I am using canvas width and height `<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check this sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/chartjs-hbjrf

It does work.May be try clearing your cache and then try

Comment: I updated your sandbox `<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>` and the same problem appeared.

Comment: add this scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true
        }
      ]
    } as an extra option. since it draws y axes

Comment: In this stuation, if I have 2 dataset, tha same problem appears.

Comment: @barteloma would you replicate  your issue in the sandbox link provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208915/discussion-between-sv12-and-barteloma).

Answer (score 0):

Solution here:

```
this.chart = new Chart(
    this.canvasContext,
    {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Population (millions)",
            backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
            data: [2478,5267,734,784,433]
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        showScale: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        utoutPercentage: 50,
        animation: {
          animateRotate: true,
          duration: 2000,
          animateScale: true
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [
             {
                 stacked: true
             }
           ],
          yAxes: [
             {
                 stacked: true
             }
           ]
         }
      }
    }
  )
```

Just add 1 more option about scales x and y axes.

Comment: i don't know the best reason for this case, but i think it maybe a small bug not for any reason when you put the width and height to style the canvas

Comment: In this stuatin, if I have 2 dataset, tha same problem appears.

Comment: @barteloma can you share it on codesanbox ? we can find the answer for your problem